# after close popup overlay as it is, i want to remove it

Tags: c#, asp.net

after close the popup display's overlay not remove ,
i write javascript and it's button code 
plz help me

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

   $(function () {

       var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');

       $('#Button1').click(function () {


           overlay.fadeIn(1000);
           overlay.appendTo(document.body);
           $('#popup').fadeIn(1000);
       }
        );

       $('.close').click(function () {
           $('.popup').hide();
           overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
           return false;
       });

       $('.x').click(function () {
           $('.popup').fadeOut(1000);
           overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();

           return false;
       });

   });
```

and some other code

```
   <div class="popup" id="Div1">
    <div class='cnt23'>

        <img src="../images/Power-Shutdown-2.png" class='x' id='Img1' />
        <br />
        <br />
        <form action="" method="post">

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

how i can remove overlay that is display after close popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update same that:

```
$('.close').click(function () {
           $('.popup').hide();
           $('#overlay').remove()
           return false;
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're appending it to the document a second time and then removing the second one:

```
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
```

The first one remains unaffected.

If the overlay is already on the document, then you can reference it by its `id`.  Something like this:

```
$('#overlay').remove();
```

---

You may even be able to remove the previously appended variable (haven't tested this, but worth a try):

```
overlay.remove();
```

Or perhaps, before attempting the above, update the variable when originally setting it to the one which was appended (in `$('#Button1').click`:

```
overlay = overlay.appendTo(document.body);
```

If that works (again, haven't tested it, just an idea) then it would remove the need to query the document again with the main jQuery function.